# MariaDB - Inconsistent behaviour when preparing a statement with CAST

Tags: mysql, casting, mariadb

A prepared query throws an error in MariaDB 10.1.44 and none in MariaDB 10.3.16:

```
PREPARE stmt FROM "SET @param = CAST(? AS VARCHAR(11))"
```

throws:

```
"#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'VARCHAR(11))' at line 1"
```

MariaDB 10.1.44 - ERROR
MariaDB 10.3.16 - OK

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently in the earlier version `VARCHAR` is not accepted as a datatype, only `CHAR`

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_cast.asp